# Mysql retornar JSON

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Eu estou tentando fazer este exemplo mas, está dando o erro:   #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'JSON_OBJECT'

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT('City', Name, 'Dist', District, 'Pop', Population) FROM City;
```

[exemplo de sql retornando Json](http://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com.br/2017/01/using-mysql-to-output-json.html)

Comment: @MarceloRafael versão Mysql 5.7.17 Eu não sabia. Eu vou tentar atualizar então.

Comment: @MarceloRafael Eu atualizei a versão do MySQL. Ficou a versão 5.7.20-log e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação:

> "Two aggregate functions generating JSON values are available (MySQL 5.7.22 and later)"

Você pode verificar a versão do seu mysql com essa query:
`show variables like '%version%';`

De acordo com o que você disse:

> @MarceloRafael versão Mysql 5.7.17 Eu não sabia. Eu vou tentar atualizar então.

**Dica:** verifica a versão Mysql da sua hospedagem.